# facebook ios sdk isn't working. iphone

Tags: iphone, facebook, sdk

I followed all the steps from here http://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-ios/ (Adding SDK & framework dependencies, Adding SQLite and the -ObjC linker flag, Adding the Facebook App ID), but I can't figure out why I get the error

```
Use of undeclared identifier 'FBSettings'
```

when I put

```
[FBSettings publishInstall:YOUR_APP_ID];
```

into

```
(void)applicationDidBecomeActive in AppDelegate.
```

Comment: which is your xcode version??

Comment: the xcode version is 4.6

Answer (score 1):

Ok.  I found the solution.  I'm seeing the "fb_mobile_activate_app" event show up in the [App Dashboard](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/) -> Insights -> App Events -> Overview

What I did:

- Followed the [iOS Getting Started](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/) instructions.
- Added the deprecated headers, I'm sure there is a better way to do this but it worked for me.  Add the headers by dragging the DeprecatedHeaders folder from the FacebookSDK.framework/Versions/A/DeprecatedHeaders folder into the Frameworks section of your Project Navigator. Choose 'Create groups for any added folders' and deselect 'Copy items into destination group's folder (if needed)'. This adds the headers as a reference.
- Then I followed the [Add the Facebook SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ads-for-apps/mobile-app-ads/#add-sdk) instructions which was just adding the following code to the AppDeligate.m file right before the '@end' at the bottom of the file.  This code should tell Facebook that the app was opened and that the app was installed from an ad click (DON"T FORGET TO CHANGE YOUR_APP_ID WITH YOUR FACEBOOK APP ID):

  ```
  - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
      NSLog(@"Application did become active.");
      [FBSettings setDefaultAppID:@"YOUR_APP_ID"];
      [FBAppEvents activateApp];
  }
  ```
- Added the this include to the very top of the AppDeligate.m file:

  ```
  #import "FacebookSDK.h"
  ```

That's it.  I now have this code in the app store and I'm getting install data for Facebook Ads.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but I just added:

```
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>
```

And that got rid of my error.

See the demo ~/Documents/FacebookSDK/Samples/HelloFacebookSample to see it in action

Answer (score 0):

You also have to import AdSupport.framework and Social.framework.

Comment: I imported them. I followed the tutorial mentioned above.:)